# Подсчет количества не прочитанных сообщений

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, есть такой подсчет.

```
 <?php
    $queryps=$bd->query("SELECT COUNT(id_ms) FROM messages WHERE from_id!=$myrow2[id] AND is_read='0'");
    $pos = $queryps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    ?>
```

Где переменная `$myrow2[id]` ровняется моему id. Проблема в том что вот есть 2 пользователя у первого выводит правильно например 3, а у второго например тоже 3 не прочитанных, но выводит почему то место 3, 13. Помогите, пожалуйста, где моя ошибка?

Comment: Потому что из таблицы выбиратся все записи, кроме принадлежащих текущему пользователю. Кэп.

Comment: @Fike from_id!=$myrow2[id] здесь проблема подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, вы б хоть схему таблицы привели

Comment: @Fike
Схема таблицы такова 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id_ms` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_hash` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `timemsg` datetime NOT NULL,
  `is_read` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `from_user_delete` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `to_user_delete` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ms`),
  KEY `from_id` (`from_id`),
  KEY `is_read` (`is_read`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: @Fike
INSERT INTO `messages` (`id_ms`, `group_hash`, `from_id`, `message`, `timemsg`, `is_read`, `from_user_delete`, `to_user_delete`) VALUES
(63, 29542, 6, 'Что ты делаешь?', '2014-05-03 09:00:24', '1', 0, 0),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$queryps=$bd->query("SELECT COUNT(id_ms) FROM messages WHERE from_id=".$myrow2['id']." AND is_read='0'");
```

Попробуйте так и не пишите никогда переменные PHP в кавычках! Это мой совет на будущее.

Comment: @Nik555 Спасибо вам большое, а почему не надо писать? нагружает сервер или просто не правильно? или дольше код выполняется?

Comment: Когда я начинал изучать PHP, я сразу старался запоминать, как лучше и оптимизированно писать код. Переменные, заключенные в двойных ковычках сильно замедляют интерпретатор PHP, особенно это можно заметить в больших циклах. Рекомендуют даже чаще использовать одинарные ковычки, если в них не встречаются спецсимволы \t,\n.
<?php
echo 'Переменная str = '.$str; // этот код более быстрый.
echo "Переменная str = $str"; // результат тот же, но медленнее.
?>
Конечно, если нужно вывести всего лишь одну строку, то особой разницы не будет заметно, но лучше сразу привыкать писать код оптимизированно.

Comment: @Nik555, я сам фанат одинарных кавычек, но сколько, по-вашему, тратится на парсинг строк в двойных кавычках?

http://ideone.com/MOENnx - этот пример говорит о 125-130% от времени парсинга на одинарных. Тот же скрипт на моем ноутбуке говорит о разнице порядка 4% **не в пользу** одинарных, подозреваю, это подсуетились создатели php.

Но самый смак не в этом, а в том, что любой большой цикл, обращение к базе или не очень эффективный алгоритм хэширования практически гарантированно потребляет больше процессорного времени, чем вся работа со строками вне циклов в приложении.

Comment: Ну и отдельно замечу, что сам цикл по времени выполнения лежит в похожих значениях (опять же, на моем ноутбуке он почему-то жрет больше, чем просто операции со строками).

Comment: Это зависит еще от сервера и от версии PHP.
Вот результат этого скрипта на моем личном серваке, у меня версия PHP 5.4.23 :)
float(0.041002035140991)
float(0.20201182365417)
float(0.18901014328003)
float(0.16100978851318)
float(0.14800810813904)

Comment: @Nik555, я написал про версии, сервер в этом соотношении вряд ли играет какую-то роль. Ну и в выводе выше - разница в 10%.

Comment: @Fike, с массивами наверное будет хуже время, напр.: $str = "key = $key[$val]"; Но вывод один - все же одинарные кавычки немного экономят процессорное время :) А если учесть, что на серваке-хостинге одновременно могут выполнятся сотни процессов, то в сумме будет ощутимо.

Comment: @Nik555, я уже выше обосновал, почему это ощутимо не будет. Потому что если весь скрипт состоит из одних строк, то его можно будет ускорить на 25%. Ни один скрипт не будет состоять только из строк.